# Addition fails in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a loop in a create-action in a rails controller like this:

```
def create
  @day = current_user.days.build(day_params)
  id = @day.tasks.first.id
  begin
    id = id + 1
  end until id = @day.tasks.id
  @day.save
  ...
end
```

when the code reaches `id = id + 1` it fails and I get the error:

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

I have no idea why this should not work...
Could there be an issue because it is a nested model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `id` isn't previously declared.

Do this:

```
id = 0

begin
  id = id + 1
end until ...
```

Once you assign an integer to a variable (in this case, `id`) it becomes an `Integer` type, which then allows you to increment in that manner

**Update**

After seeing your edits to your question, the problem is because `id` is still blank.

The `id` of a record does not get assigned until you actually *create* the record. Using `build` will not generate an ID because it has not yet been added to the database.

Comment: of course i declared it previously, sry I forgot that in my post

Comment: @Max you're saying that in spite of having declared it, you're still seeing this `nil:NilClass` problem?

Comment: @MarsAtomic yes, thats the case and I doublecheckt that the declaration is working

Comment: @Max OK, then we need to see the actual code. Where and how did you declare ID?

Comment: @Max I've updated my answer to reflect your updated question